# In Mobile First 6.3 how can we prevent shared preference file

Tags: sharedpreferences, ibm-mobilefirst

We are creating an android application in MF 6.3. When we are building our project and passing the application url and context path in the "Build Setting And Deploy Target". These entries is save in the shared preference of apk in WLPrefs.xml file in the flat file like this.

https://localhost:0443/worklight

If we have jail-braked device we can extract this URL.

Is there is any way to encrypt these shared preference entries in Mobile First 6.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IBM offers product integration with the Trusteer SDK that can detect rooted devices in the case of Android (only iOS devices are termed "jail broken") and allow you to, for example, disallow running the app.

You can read more about Trusteer integration here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/integration/trusteer-android-integration/

You can also attempt to use Android ProGuard; not sure it'll help.
It is not officially supported in v6.3, but the instructions for 7.0 may work for 6.3 as well: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_pg_obfus_intro.html